# Create a boundary around polygons (ST_ExteriorRing?)

Tags: postgis

I have a geometry of polygons, which are boxes that make a grid over an area.

I'd like to query the boundary of the outer most boxes of the grid.

It looked like `ST_ExteriorRing` might be the solution, but this query mirrors my existing geometry exactly.

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_ExteriorRing(geom)) AS bounds
    FROM myzones
```

How would I retrieve a bounding box that outlines the outer most border of my grid?

Note: Even though my geom is made up of boxes, the shape of all of them is not square.

Answer (score 0):

St_Exteriorring is not an aggregate operator, so you'll a get an output record for every input record.

I think you need either [st_union](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) or [st_collect](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) (st_collect might be quicker, but it might cause the st_exteriorring to fail if it returns a geometrycollection): i.e.

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_ExteriorRing(st_union(geom))) AS bounds
     FROM myzones
```